# Invisible Box2d Sprite using Position?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Creating an CCNode, setting it to my player's position- in debug draw I see the physics object, but the sprite is invisible or nil or something. It doesn't crash the sprite simply doesn't appear.  The bomb also travels the proper path and it's selector method is called.

Does NOT Appear:

```
GameObject *bomb = [_useBombArray nextSprite];
bomb.tag = kShipMissile;
[bomb stopAllActions];
NSLog(@"_bombSpawnPoint: %.0f, %.0f", _bombSpawnPoint.x, _bombSpawnPoint.y);
bomb.position = _bombSpawnPoint;
```

I have gotten it to appear by doing this:

```
GameObject *bomb = [_useBombArray nextSprite];
bomb.tag = kShipMissile;
[bomb stopAllActions];
bomb.position = ccp(_winSize.width * 0.5, _winSize.width * 0.5);
```

The _bombSpawnPoint is set prior to this and I do receive proper results on output.

Originally I thought I had called to create the object at an inopportune time in the update. So I changed the function slightly, to be sure it is called in proper order in the update method.

Not sure what's causing this! Please help!
I've created all my objects like this and they've all worked perfectly thus far!

Comment: any idea... struggling with this :S I can provide more detail if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The result of this was caused by the Texture of the Bomb was not in the proper BatchNode.
The error was not triggering until I removed the excess subclasses and used solely the sprite.

The error received was: `'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'`

Once I used the other batch node everything worked perfect. Hope this helps someone!